# Data transfer from an device to iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a POC in which a eletronic device is collecting some data. These data has to transfer from the device to iphone device via Bluetooth.

Is it possible. A guideline or any reference will do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea was POC means. Several ideas, though:

- To use BT comms on plain iOS devices, you'll need to get in touch with Apple directly, thru the route that also gets you access to "made for iPhone" hardware access (Dock connector etc.). You'll have to fill out a form and sign an NDA, and then you should be able to get docs on how to use BT to connect to other devices that you know (not to any, though, I believe - you have to specify the BT device's ID codes).
- If you need this only to run on a few devices that you have at hand, consider jailbreaking them - then you might find open source bluetooth code and help on the net, as others have added new BT features to jailbroken iOS devices.

Comment: POC means proof of concept or in other way a sample app for the concept you are working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Is there any guideline of the process to be followed.

Comment: Oh, then, I'm afraid, you're stuck. Unless you poke at the innards of the private iOS frameworks, trying to figure out what they do and use them on your private device (won't get you thru Apple's review process, but for a POC it should be sufficient, right?). Again, jailbreaking your development device might help here as it allows you better access to the OS files for testing. Sorry, can't give you more specifics as I've not dived into it myself, although I've consired writing a BT app for the iPhone, too, in the past. Let us know what you find if you do!

Comment: re guidelines: I'd either see what the jailbreak community found out, or go here: http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ - can take a while to get thru that process, though.